# Creating a collection of methods to call with parameters specified

Tags: c#, collections, delegates

I want to do the following, but can't quite get there. I have a datagridview on a form that I want to set the source to a different datatable each time I click the button.

```
DynamicsTableAccess ta;   
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //the DataSource for both calls will be a DataTable
   //first button click
   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate(new object[] { "REPT0000", DateTime.Parse("1/18/2012"), 3});
   //second button click
   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(new object[] { "01254785", "01254885", 3 });
   //etc
}
```

I think I need to use some type of collection that can hold each of my database calls, like:

```
Foo.Add(ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate(new object[] { "REPT0000", DateTime.Parse("1/18/2012"), 3}));
Foo.Add(ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(new object[] { "01254785", "01254885", 3 }));
```

Then iterate over that collection on each button click:

```
int index = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Foo[index];
   index++;
}
```

I realize this is probably going to require a delegate of some sort, if it's possible, and I generally can wrap my head around them, but not this time.

I realize that this is nothing that should ever end up in production code, I'm only using it to test my database calls and will bury it once that's finished. I'm open to suggestions on completely different approaches, but mostly am looking for how to construct Foo to accomplish this particular goal.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a client app, based on the lack of `DataBind()` calls that would be present in a web app...

Comment: What datatype is returned by ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate and ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange?  DataTable?  DataSet?

Comment: Tejs correct Chris Shain DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate` and `ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange` both return a `DataTable`; if not, just replace any `DataTable` occurrences below with the appropriate type.

The problem with your code is that you’re executing the said methods before adding them to the list, thereby effectively only storing their result in the list. Instead, you need to store an encapsulation of their execution for a later time. To achieve the latter, as you suggested, you need to use delegates. In C# 3.5, the syntax required for declaring delegates has been appreciably simplified through the introduction of [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx); I would suggest you read up on them.

Thus, we first declare your `Foo` list (presumably as a class instance variable) to hold the delegates (or functions) we wish to execute later.

```
List<Func<DataSet>> Foo = new List<Func<DataTable>>();
```

Then, we may add our method calls, encapsulated as anonymous functions, to the list. Note that the `() =>` syntax causes any statement that succeeds it to get encapsulated as an anonymous function.

```
Foo.Add(() => ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate(new object[] { "REPT0000", DateTime.Parse("1/18/2012"), 3}));
Foo.Add(() => ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(new object[] { "01254785", "01254885", 3 }));
```

Finally, we simply need to get a reference to one of the delegates from the list – `Foo[index]` – and invoke it by appending the `()` normally associated with method calls.

```
int index = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Clear();
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Foo[index]();
    index++;
}
```

**Edit**: What you were trying would have given you something like this:

```
List<Func<object[], DataTable>> Foo = new List<Func<object[], DataTable>>();
Foo.Add((objs) => ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate(objs));
Foo.Add((objs) => ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(objs));
```

…or, more succinctly using collection initializers:

```
var Foo = new List<Func<object[], DataTable>>()
{
    (objs) => ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate(objs),
    (objs) => ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(objs), 
};
```

…or, even more succinctly:

```
var Foo = new List<Func<object[], DataTable>>()
{
    ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate,
    ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange, 
};
```

However, you would then need to supply the corresponding argument for each anonymous function in order for it to be invoked.

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Foo[0](new object[] { "REPT0000", DateTime.Parse("1/18/2012"), 3});
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Foo[1](new object[] { "01254785", "01254885", 3 });
```

In this case, such would be undesirable since you were trying to encapsulate the entire method call, including the given arguments, as part of your anonymous function. You could tell that the original anonymous function was more ‘complete’ because its type was `Func<DataTable>`, meaning that it had a return type of `DataTable` but did not accept any arguments.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but did `List<Func<DataTable, object[]>> Foo = new List<Func<DataTable, object>>()` my first time around, and when that didn't work, came here. I knew a lambda would work, just needed to simplify.

Comment: It would have been the other way round `List<Func<object[], DataTable>>`, but then the `object[]` parameters would have to be supplied at each call.

Answer (score 1):

Your assuming that your `GetLineItemsByDocumentRange` method is defined like this:

```
public DataTable GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(object[] filter)
{
}
```

Define filters like this:

```
List<Func<DataTable>> filters = new List<Func<DataTable>>();
filters.Add(() => ta.GetLineItemsByCustomerAndDate(new object[] { "REPT0000", DateTime.Parse("1/18/2012"), 3}));
filters.Add(() => ta.GetLineItemsByDocumentRange(new object[] { "01254785", "01254885", 3 }));
```

Each time you call

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = filters[index]();
```

The filter will be reevaluated, returning the current customers.